# Getting Error while writing Data in GoogleSheet Using R

Tags: r, dataframe, google-sheets, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm using below-mentioned code to write the dataframe in Google sheet using R, but getting the following error.

```
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
  * Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
```

Code that I'm using:

DF

```
library(googlesheets4)
options(httr_oob_default=TRUE)

write_sheet(DF, "15XfCb-MpRm4jiIn0P3xg40MlIjna2YSfeq4Il0LNPEE", sheet = 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: How are you running this code, as a script? It looks like the package doesn't find the credentials to authenticate.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I'm running in R, I have tried to remove the library and re-install it.

Comment: What I mean is are you running this interactively or via some scripting mechanism like `R scriptname.R` or `Rscript scriptname.R`? The error would suggest this. If you're executing the code interactively, perhaps you should look into the documentation on how to authenticate your session before trying to execute any commands.